# 'google' is undefined error in IE11

Tags: winforms, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using below html code for using google maps in WebBrowser in my WinForms application.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 600px;
        width: 100%;
       }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      var prevLat = 0;
      var prevLon = 0;

      function initMap() {
        var centerPoint = {lat: 12.9716, lng: 77.5946};
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 15,
          center: centerPoint
        });
      }

      function AddPoint(latitude, longitude, heading, fixTypeColor, portNumber){

                if(prevLat == 0 && prevLon == 0)
                {               
                    var Coordinates = [
                    {lat: latitude, lng: longitude}
                    ];
                }
                else
                {
                    var Coordinates = [
                    {lat: prevLat, lng: prevLon},
                    {lat: latitude, lng: longitude}
                    ];
                }

                prevLat = latitude;
                prevLon = longitude;

                var newPoint = {lat: latitude, lng: longitude};

                var lineSymbol = {
                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_OPEN_ARROW,
                rotation: heading
                };

                var polyLine = new google.maps.Polyline({
                    map: map,
                    path: Coordinates,
                    icons: [{
                        icon: lineSymbol,
                        fixedRotation: true,
                        offset: '100%'
                    }],
                    geodesic: true,
                    strokeColor: fixTypeColor,
                    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                    strokeWeight: 2
                    });

                map.panTo(newPoint);
          }

    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=my_key&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When WebBrowser is launched, I am getting the following error:

Line: 48
Char: 5
Error: 'google' is undefined
Code: 0

However, the map is working fine after I click Yes for this exception.

Please help me in fixing this exception.

P.S. I have replaced Google Maps JavaScript API Key with 'my_key' here.

Comment: I don't see any errors in IE11 with the posted code.

Comment: Hi @geocodezip, I am getting the exception when function AddPoint() is called for the first time. Once I click Ok, exception never comes again.

Comment: The posted code doesn't call the `AddPoint` function.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @geocodezip : I am able to solve the issue now. The reason for the issue was AddPoint() function being called before Google Maps JavaScript API is loaded completely. Hence the 'google' is undefined error. I am now setting a flag at the end of initMap() function and I am implementing the AddPoint() only if the flag is set as true.